# Move question to Programmers

Tags: discussion, migration

There is a question about [data storage in Android without SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246376/data-storage-without-sqlite). As of its [meta-post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305292/please-explain-why-this-question-was-closed-as-off-topic/305295#305295), it was at first proposed to belong to Programmers (and later retracted).

It specifies the kind of data and the use case, and that it needs to be on android, so this is (hopefully) not too broad, as "What is the best book to learn Java from"?

It is a question about a recommendation, yet it does not require any products, it is more about the technology type to use (ORM vs some kind of NoSQL).

Does that question belong to Programmers, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking whether a relational database or a graph database or some other kind of database is the more appropriate design for a given set of requirements can be on-topic here. **However, most of the reasons this question is considered a poor fit for StackOverflow in its current form are also reasons why it would be a poor fit on any SE site**, even if it is on-topic here.

In particular, the requirements you specify (which would be relevant to an answer) are:

> They do not need transactions, ACID, and such. They need to be queried, though.

Which is not enough to rule out any form of data storage at all. Even using a simple text file which you read into a `std::map<X, Y>` at startup is enough to allow basic querying. Also, I'm not sure I believe that any use case doesn't require any part of ACID; maybe you don't need things like rollback but I'm sure everyone wants atomicity and consistency at least.

Thus, *as currently written* your requirements simply aren't specific enough to make the question *answerable*. At best it is *discussable*, but even that discussion would mostly consist of us asking you to give more detail about your requirements. For instance: what kinds of queries, are there multiple types of entities, are there any relationships, do you ever do insertion/deletion or only querying, do you need multiple threads querying, is this a client-side only database or is it being queried via a web API, etc, etc.

Comment: Excerpts of this (excellent) answer were copy-pasted (by me) to the [meta.SE question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305292/please-explain-why-this-question-was-closed-as-off-topic)'s answer. It clarifies a bit more what was wrong with the question.

Comment: Would you examine the update, or do you want me to post a new meta question?

Comment: @user------- I don't think I have the time to follow-up on this, so since you have enough rep to join chats, see if anyone in our chat room (The Whiteboard) would be willing to re-evaluate your question and help improve it further. If no one responds, then try another meta Q.

Comment: ok. Good idea. Thanks for a very clear answer.